# Kentico editor_styles double editing windows

Tags: kentico

When I go to edit my editor_styles in Kentico 11, I get two windows. I've never seen this before and it doesn't happen in many other instances of Kentico that I'm running. Has anyone ever seen this before?

I tried clearing the cache, restarting the site, etc

[image]

**EDIT: Just had to resign all macros and now all is ok again**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things could cause this:

1. Cache.  Could be browser cache or server cache so be sure you've cleared ALL your cache, especially if you've recently applied an upgrade or a hotfix.
2. Macro signatures from an upgrade or change in your hash string salt. Be sure to resign all your macros
3. Upgrade/hotfix application.  If you've recently upgraded or applied a  hotfix, it could be a dll mismatch or some js file which was not overwritten.  Check the upgrade/hotfix log file for possible issues.

Comment: it was the macros!